# I want to retrieve the id from the query result and reuse it for the next query laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to use the id from the select query results, then I want to use that id again to find data using wherein. but the error i found,

```
 public function getMaut(){

        $merek="samsung";
        $tipe="led TV";
        $display ="25-32";
        $kriteria=Kriteria::all();
        $alternatif = Alternatif::where('merek',$merek)->where('tipe',$tipe)->where('display',$display)->get();
        $alternatif_id = (array)$alternatif->id;   
        $nilaialter = Nilaialternatif::whereIn('id_alternatifs',$alternatif_id);
     
        return view('spk.index',compact('kriteria','alternatif','nilaialter','alternatif_id'));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `pluck` method to retrieve all values for a given key.

```
$alternatif = Alternatif::where('merek', $merek)->where('tipe', $tipe)->where('display', $display)->get();
$alternatif_id = $alternatif->pluck('id');   
$nilaialter = Nilaialternatif::whereIn('id_alternatifs', $alternatif_id)->get();
```

Alternatively, you can create a hasMany relation to 'Nilaialternatif' at 'Alternatif' model.

```
class Alternatif extends Model 
{
    public function nilaialternatifs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Nilaialternatif::class, 'id_alternatifs');
    }
}
```

Then query the relationship like

```
$alternatif = Alternatif::with('nilaialternatifs')->where('merek', $merek)->where('tipe', $tipe)->where('display', $display)->get();
$nilaialter = $alternatif->nilaialternatifs;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $nilaialter = [];
    $alternatif = Alternatif::where('merek', $merek)->where('tipe', $tipe)->where('display', $display)->get()->toArray();
    if (count($alternatif)) {
        $alternatif_ids = collect($alternatif)->pluck('id')->toArray();
        $nilaialter = Nilaialternatif::whereIn('id_alternatifs', $alternatif_ids)->get()->toArray();
    }
```

use laravel collection, https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections

use pluck method of collection,https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-pluck